# Rate module thumbs up / down widget with button

Tags: views, 7, theming, rating

I am using rate module to count likes and dislikes. Here I am using Thumbs up / down widget. My question is that how can I show a button below thumbs up and dislike button below thumbs down.

In  the image given below there is text "Total likes". Here I would like to place a button and this button should provide same functionality that thumbs up is providing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i found answer of my question.
find rate-template-thumbs-up-down.tpl.php file in rate -> templates -> rate-template-thumbs-up-down.tpl.php

copy this file and place in your_theme/templates folder.

then override this file by below code:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Rate widget theme
 */
 ?>

 <?php
 /*
 <div class="rate-label">
 <?php print $display_options['title']; ?>
 </div>
 */
 ?>
 <div class="like-container">
 <div class="likes">
 <span>
 <img src="<?php print base_path() . drupal_get_path('theme', 'bartik'); ?      
 >/images/likes.png"></span>
 <span><?php print $results['up']; ?></span>
 <span> total likes</span>
 </div>
 <button class="likes-button"><?php
 print theme('rate_button', array(
  'text' => t('Likes'),
  'href' => $links[0]['href'],
  'class' => "likes-button-link")
 );

 ?></button>
 </div>

 <div class="dislike-container">
 <div class="dislikes">
 <span>
 <img src="<?php print base_path() . drupal_get_path('theme', 'bartik'); ? 
 >/images/dislikes.png">
 </span>
 <span><?php print $results['down']; ?></span>
 <span> total dislikes</span>
 </div>
 <button><?php
 print theme('rate_button', array(
  'text' => t('Dislikes'),
  'href' => $links[1]['href'],
  'class' => "dislikes-button-link")
 );
 ?></button>
 </div>
```